# count increase by number, not digits

Tags: python, string

In this python function the file number increases by one when saving.
It does it from filename1 to filename10 correctly and then jumps to 111, 1112, 11113 and so forth instead of continuing with filename11.
Where does it go wrong?

```
for f in notepad.getFiles():                                                 
    if os.path.isfile(f[0]):                                         
        notepad.activateBufferID(f[1])                               
        if notepad.getCurrentBufferID() == f[1]:                     
            notepad.save()                                           
    else:                                                            
        notepad.activateBufferID(f[1])                               
        if notepad.getCurrentBufferID() == f[1]:                     
            counter = 0                                              
            filename = f[0]                                          
            while os.path.isfile(NewFileDir + filename + NewFileExt):
                counter += 1                                         
                filename = filename[:-1] + str(counter)              
            notepad.saveAs(NewFileDir + filename + NewFileExt)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offending line is here:

```
filename = filename[:-1] + str(counter)
```

You trim off **one** character and add the counter. This works great for filenames when the counter is a single digit:

```
filename8 -> filename + 9
filename9 -> filename + 10
```

but fails when the counter is more than one digit:

```
filename10 -> filename1 + 11
filename111 -> filename11 + 12
```

One solution would be to use `len(str(counter))` instead of hardcoding `[:-1]`. Another would be to store the base filename separately instead of mutating it as you go.